# setting method with int

Tags: objective-c, xcode, methods, int

i have a method and when i want to set an argument(which type is `int`) i get an error message.
my code:

```
@implementation PlayerInfo

@synthesize playerName;
@synthesize playerScore;

-(id) initPlayerInfo:(NSString*) name playerScore:(int) score
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self)
    {
        self.playerName = name;
        self.playerScore = score;
    }

    return self;
}
```

i get an error in this line:

```
self.playerScore = score;
```

what is the problem??

thanks!!

Comment: First, what's the error message?

Comment: How's `playerScore` declared?

Comment: playScore declare like this: @property (nonatomic, assign) int *playerScore;

Answer (score 2):

You declared the property as a pointer to an int (that is, `int *`) rather than an int (which is just `int`). Despite both including the keyword `int`, they are very different things.

Answer (score -1):

playerScore must be (nonatomic, assign) check that. Or when you init PlayerInfo instance you should give a value for score

Comment: Can't tell that from the information given.  You're assuming it's an int, which it probably is, but until the OP clarifies, this answer may be wrong.